# Selenium's find elements using the By is not working for the CSS selector , it is giving empty list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_driver_path = YOUR CHROME DRIVER PATH
S = Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=S)
url = "https://www.python.org/"
driver.get(url)

event_time = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".event-widget last time")
print(event_time)
```

After printing the event_time , it is giving me empty list

Can somebody help to find this

Comment: find_elements returns a webreference array.  Seems like you'd need something like this: time=event_time[index].text

Comment: .event-widget last time -> .event-widget.last.time missed the . for class names. Also don't find an element with that css selector anyways found one with .event-widget.last for upcoming events.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and helping me out. I need one more clarity looks like "find_element_by_link_text" this method is deprecated  in the latest releases. Can somebody help to get the proper syntax for this that should work.